# "Publish" PHP functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am still pretty new to PHP but I was reading through WordPress pages to get ideas for my own site and saw `<?php get_header(); ?>` and I remembered that I have always wondered how the developers of WordPress made these "public functions"

There is probably a real name for them and they probably aren't even functions but I have been wondering if I could create something like this for my own website. I know you can use `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` but what if for some reason I want to be really lazy or have long file names/paths? Could I make it simple and quick?

Comment: Well, you might consider to use php [class autoloading](http://php.net/autoload). There are many ways.

Comment: @CORRUPT: In the example above, `get_header()` is not a class method. That's one of the reasons that makes the Wordpress codebase a pretty bad example. They pollute the global namespace with a whole bunch of functions.

Comment: @xbonez yeah, maybe. "functional approach vs oop approach" is very long discussion topic, to present here. Well, I consider this question as "too broad" or "unclear". There is nothing else here I can help with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your own website, you can create functions that wrap long file names for includes. This approach can work whether you are encapsulating the function in a class, or if you are leaving it in the global namespace (as others have suggested...that's another topic for debate).

If writing your function in the global namespace, you may want to consider wrapping your function declaration in an IF statement that checks to see if the function has already been declared. This might allow other developers to replace your method with their own (for example if you are including a view or something visual they want to replace).